# How to use Attribute Exchange (AX) with php-openid?

Tags: php, openid, janrain, openid-provider

We are working with php-openid library of Janrain. There is no documentation or example about how to use the AX.php class and configure it on the OpenID provider/server.

We found one thread about this with an consumer/client 
example: [Example usage of AX in PHP OpenID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183788/example-usage-of-ax-in-php-openid)

The Attribute Exchange types we would like to use on both provider and consumer are defined here: http://web.archive.org/web/20100827030457/http://www.axschema.org/types/

Can someone please explain me, how to use the AX class on both provider and consumer?
Also in with file(s) I need to make changes?

Comment: See [Example usage of AX in PHP OpenID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183788/example-usage-of-ax-in-php-openid).